# Update or destroy popup in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, popup, update

I am doing a map which refresh dinamically all markers when they get modified.
I want to add popups to show some info.

I create popups this way:

```
        var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(markers, location); //location = lonlat
        feature.closeBox = true;
        feature.popupClass = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud, {
        'autoSize': true
    });;
        feature.data.popupContentHTML = "info"; 
        feature.data.overflow = (false) ? "auto" : "hidden";        
            var markerClick = function (evt) {
            if (this.popup == null) {
                this.popup = this.createPopup(this.closeBox);
                map.addPopup(this.popup);
                this.popup.show();
            } else {
                this.popup.toggle();
            }
            currentPopup = this.popup;
            OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
        };
        mark.events.register("mousedown", feature, markerClick);
```

Now, I have the problem about what to do if one of my markers update its info. How can I destroy the popup? (I will create other one) or how can I modifiy it? Can I access them using lonlat?

Sometimes, I want to delete all of them, is there a way to do that? like deleting a layer or something?

Answer (score 6):

for getting one popup info, you should do this:

```
map.popups[0]; // the firstly added popup
```

for removing one popup:

```
map.removePopup(map.popups[0]); // it will destroy firstly added popup
map.popups[0].destroy() // the same thing
```

for removing all popup from maps:

```
var pops = map.popups;
for(var a = 0; a < pops.length; a++){
   map.removePopup(map.popups[a]);
};
```

for hiding and showing popups:

```
map.popups[0].hide()
map.popups[0].show()
```

for finding popups from lonlat, you can get info for looping it in for loop and if clause:

```
map.popups[0].lonlat.lon
map.popups[0].lonlat.lat
```

and you can get the last popup with following code:

```
map.popups[0].getLast()
```

this all information is some part of Openlayers popup element...there are lots of thing you can do with popups...

i hope it helps you

Answer (score -2):

Did you take a look at the OpenLayers.Map documentation? All popups are accessible from the "map" variable.

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.popups

Comment: it would be better if you could explain the answer rather than just providing a link